# Smoothen the result of FindRoot

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, mathematical-optimization

I have a set of code for which it involves finding the corresponding `c` for each `a` (although I will give a value of `a` later) and `z` using the constraint `toroot[a,c,z]` and then substituting `c` back into the final expression `functionS[a,z]`. I also have another function for which there is a change of variable `functionSR[l,z]` where `a->l-0.01`.

```
d = 3;
zh = 1.5;
toroot[a_, c_?NumericQ, z_] := a - NIntegrate[(c z^(d + 1) x^d)/((1 - ((z x)/zh)^(d + 1)) (1 - c^2 (z x)^(2 d)))^(1/2), {x, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 4, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
cz[a_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := c /. FindRoot[toroot[a, c, z], {c, 0.0009, 0.0000001, 10000}, WorkingPrecision -> 5]
intS[a_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[With[{b = z/zh}, (((-1)/(d - 1)) cz[a, z]^2 z^(2 d)) x^d ((1 - (b x)^(d + 1))/(1 - cz[a, z]^2 (z x)^(2 d)))^(1/2) - ((b^(d + 1) (d + 1))/(2 (d - 1))) x ((1 - cz[a, z]^2 (z x)^(2 d))/(1 - (b x)^(d + 1)))^(1/2) + (b^(d + 1) x)/((1 - (b x)^(d + 1)) (1 - cz[a, z]^2 (z x)^(2 d)))^(1/2)], {x, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 4, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
functionS[a_, z_] = ((-((1 - cz[a, z]^2 z^(2 d)) (1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1)))^(1/2)/(d - 1)) + intS[a, z] + 1)/(z^(d - 1));
functionSR[l_, z_] = Replace[functionS[a, z], a -> (l - 0.01), Infinity];
```

My problem is when I try to find the minimum of `functionS[a,z]` and `functionSR[l,z]` for some `a` and `l`, say `a=1` and `l=1`, it gives me an error. I think it is connected to the behavior of `c` when `a=1` or `l=1`.

```
In[23]:= FindMinimum[functionS[1, z], {z, 1.2, 1.5}] // 
  Quiet // AbsoluteTiming
FindMinimum[functionSR[1, z], {z, 1.2, 1.5}] // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming

During evaluation of In[23]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 5 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.697475}. NIntegrate obtained 0.000944548 -0.00149313 I and 0.0006178735732839699` for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[23]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 5 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.697475}. NIntegrate obtained 0.000944548 -0.00149313 I and 0.0006178735732839699` for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[23]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 5 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.697475}. NIntegrate obtained 0.000949747 -0.00149122 I and 0.000620731102746343` for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[23]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::ncvb will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[23]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {1.70561} is at the edge of the search region {1.0000*10^-7,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[23]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {1.70561} is at the edge of the search region {1.0000*10^-7,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[23]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {1.70561} is at the edge of the search region {1.0000*10^-7,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[23]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::reged will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[23]:= FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value 0.436961 -1.38189 I is not a real number at {z} = {1.2}.

During evaluation of In[23]:= FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value 0.436961 -1.38189 I is not a real number at {z} = {1.2}.

Out[23]= {0.760891, FindMinimum[functionS[1, z], {z, 1.2, 1.5}]}

During evaluation of In[23]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 5 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.699811}. NIntegrate obtained 0.00286247 -0.0000971587 I and 0.0005426332486649041` for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[23]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 5 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.699811}. NIntegrate obtained 0.00286247 -0.0000971587 I and 0.0005426332486649041` for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[23]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 5 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.699811}. NIntegrate obtained 0.00286812 -0.0000961916 I and 0.0005442259497809905` for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[23]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::ncvb will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[23]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {1.68855} is at the edge of the search region {1.0000*10^-7,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[23]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {1.68855} is at the edge of the search region {1.0000*10^-7,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[23]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {1.68855} is at the edge of the search region {1.0000*10^-7,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[23]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::reged will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[23]:= FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value 0.439434 -1.36539 I is not a real number at {z} = {1.2}.

During evaluation of In[23]:= FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value 0.439434 -1.36539 I is not a real number at {z} = {1.2}.

Out[24]= {0.771827, FindMinimum[functionSR[1, z], {z, 1.2, 1.5}]}
```

For a=0.1, the plot is much more smooth

[image: 2]

For a=1, the plot contains more bumps

[image: 1]

Is my code badly written to extract `c`? Are there any changes that can be done? I have read somewhere that `Reduce` can also be used instead of `FindRoot` but I am still figuring it out. Also, is using `LocalAdaptive` as a method for `NIntegrate` suitable here?

UPDATE:
Please note of the typo, I have corrected it. In the plots before, I wrote `c=0.1` and `c=1` but it should be `a=0.1` and `a=1`.

The expressions of my problem is given by,

$$a = c z_s^{d+1}\int_0^1 dx \frac{x^d}{\sqrt{(1-(z_s/z_h)^{d+1} x^{d+1})(1-c^2 z_s^{2d} x^{2d})}} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

\begin{align}
S &= \frac{1}{4 z_s^{d-1}}\Bigg(1 -\frac{\sqrt{(1-c^2 z_s^{2d})(1-b^{d+1})}}{d-1} - \frac{1}{d-1} c^2 z_s^{2d} \int^1_0 dx x^d \sqrt{\frac{(1-(b x)^{d+1})}{(1-c^2(z_s x)^{2d})}}\\  
  & -\frac{b^{d+1}(d+1)}{2(d-1)} \int^1_0 dx x \sqrt{\frac{(1-c^2(z_s x)^{2d})}{(1-(b x)^{d+1})}}\\ 
& + b^{d+1}\int^1_0 dx \frac{x}{\sqrt{(1-(b x)^{d+1})(1-c^2(z_s x)^{2d})}}\Bigg) \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}

where $b=\frac{z_s}{z_h}$ and note that $c=c(z_s)$ (`c=c[z]`) although in the code `c=c[a,z]`, $c$ should only depend on $z_s$ (`z`) since $a$ will be specified in the end.

Also, maybe there is a better way to design finding $c$. Actually, I can have another constraint where $\frac{dS}{dz_s} = 0$ (that is because in the end I need to minimize $S$ with respect to $z_s$) and maybe the derivative of $\eqref{1}$ with respect to $z_s$, so that these can be used to find $c$?

Comment: Somehow I feel `WorkingPrecision -> 5` will always be a problem, except perhaps in academic exercises.  What do you think it accomplishes for you?

Comment: @bbgodfrey How can the only root be zero if at the plot for `a=0.1` you can see that if you just look at the range `0.3 < z <1.5` the plot is smooth and not zero although small. ALSO sorry since there is a typo, I wrote `c=0.1` and `c=1` for the plots but it should be `a=0.1` and `a=1`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 You are correct, I removed `WorkingPrecision` and still got the same plot for `c`, but that is assuming `c` is the problem. Maybe there is a better way of designing the code for `c` in accordance to that I need to define a function `functionS[a,z]` in the end.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Please see my update of the question.

Comment: My second comment, now deleted, was in error.  Sorry.

Comment: @bbgodfrey No worries! Do you think there is a better way to find $c$? Maybe it has to do on what method I used, there is also an update in my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the `NIntegrate` error messages can be seen from a factor of the integrand, `x^d/Sqrt[1-c x^d z^d]`, of `toroot`.  For `c > z^-3`, the integrand is singular for some point in the domain, `{x, 0, 1}`.  Moreover, if `NIntegrate` could integrate through the singularity (and, with help, it can), the result would be a complex number, which (presumably) is undesirable.  To proceed, change the variable of integration to `xd = x^(d+1)` and apply  the appropriate `Method` from [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#122144792).

```
toroot[a_, c_?NumericQ, z_] := a - NIntegrate[((1 - xd (z /zh)^(d + 1)) 
   (1 - c^2 xd^(2 d/(d + 1))  z^(2 d)))^(-1/2), {xd, 0, 1}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive",
    "SingularityHandler" -> "DoubleExponential"}] (c z^(d + 1))/4
```

In addition, redefine `cz` to use the secant `Method` and bound the search for `c` to between `0` and `z^-3`.

```
cz[a_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := c /. 
    FindRoot[toroot[a, c, z], {c, .5 z^-3, .6 z^-3/2, 0, z^-3}]
```

(The initial guesses, `.5 z^-3` and `.6 z^-3`, were chosen somewhat arbitrarily.)  With this definition, `cz` returns the correct value of `c`, if it exists, and `z^-3` along with the `FindRoot::reged` error message otherwise.  With these definitions, the two plots in the question can be obtained correctly as follows.  For `a = 1`,

```
Plot[Check[cz[1, z], Null], {z, 1.42, zh}, AxesLabel -> {z, c}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

`Check` prevents plotting of a short range around `c = 1.42`, where no solution exists, although it does not eliminate the corresponding error messages.  The second plot, for `a = .1`, is

```
LogPlot[Check[cz[.1, z], Null], {z, .2, zh}, AxesLabel -> {z, c}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]