# Eliminate a variable within an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

I have two expressions given by,

$$a = \int_0^1 dx \frac{c z_s^{d+1} x^d}{\sqrt{(1-(z_s/z_h)^{d+1} x^{d+1})(1-c^2 z_s^{2d} x^{2d})}} \tag{1}\label{1},$$

$$S = \int_\epsilon^{z_s} dx \frac{1}{x^d} \sqrt{\frac{1}{(1-(x/z_h)^{d+1})(1-c^2 x^{2d})}}\tag{2}\label{2},$$

where $c=c(z_s)$ and $a$ is a function of $z_s$, and $z_h$ is a constant which can be given a value later. Also, even though $a$ is a function of $z_s$ in the expression, in the final expression for $S$ I will just give it a value. $d$ is just a dimension parameter which can be given a value say, $d=3$.

The goal is to find an expression of $S$ such that $c$ is eliminated. Now, one condition which can help achieve that is,

$$\frac{dS}{dz_s} = 0\tag{3}\label{3},$$

actually I need to find an expression for the minimal $S$ (with respect to $z_s$) to which $c$ dictates.

---

I have asked some related problems before but for eq. $\eqref{2}$ in those cases I made a transformation $x=z_sy$ so that the integral limits there is $[\epsilon/z_s,1]$ and then expand out the finite and divergent terms then I just showed the finite terms there so that I allow the lower limit to be 0.

[Solving a function inside an integral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230147/solving-a-function-inside-an-integral)

[Smoothen the result of FindRoot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231195/smoothen-the-result-of-findroot)

In this case, I just start with the original integral $\eqref{2}$ and set a small number for $\epsilon$ (this is just a modification of my previous problem in order to eliminate the divergence contribution but the result should not differ for those regions far from the divergence region).

The problem is when I try to plot those same quantities I get a different result.

The previous code,

```
d = 3;
zh = 1.5;
torootL[a_, c_?NumericQ, z_] := a - NIntegrate[(c z^(d + 1) xd^(d/(d + 1)))/((1 - xd (z/zh)^(d + 1)) (1 - xd^((2 d)/(d + 1)) c^2 (z)^(2 d)))^(1/2), {xd, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 6, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> "DoubleExponential"}]
cz[a_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := c /. FindRoot[torootL[a, c, z], {c, 0.001, 0.0000001, 1000}]
intS[a_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[With[{b = z/zh}, (((-1)/(d - 1)) cz[a, z]^2 z^(2 d)) x^d ((1 - (b x)^(d + 1))/(1 - cz[a, z]^2 (z x)^(2 d)))^(1/2) - ((b^(d + 1) (d + 1))/(2 (d - 1))) x ((1 - cz[a, z]^2 (z x)^(2 d))/(1 - (b x)^(d + 1)))^(1/2) + (b^(d + 1) x)/((1 - (b x)^(d + 1)) (1 - cz[a, z]^2 (z x)^(2 d)))^(1/2)], {x, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 6, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> "DoubleExponential"}]
functionS[a_, z_] = ((-((1 - cz[a, z]^2 z^(2 d)) (1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1)))^(1/2)/(d - 1)) + intS[a, z] + 1)/(4 z^(d - 1));
Plot[functionS[0.1, z], {z, 1, zh}, PlotPoints -> 8, AxesLabel -> {"z_s", "S"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large] // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming
```

produces this plot,

[image: pic1]

The present code where I just changed the lines corresponding to the discussion I made above,

```
d = 3;
zh = 1.5;
torootL[a_, c_?NumericQ, z_] := a - NIntegrate[(c z^(d + 1) xd^(d/(d + 1)))/((1 - xd (z/zh)^(d + 1)) (1 - xd^((2 d)/(d + 1)) c^2 (z)^(2 d)))^(1/2), {xd, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 6, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> "DoubleExponential"}]
cz[a_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := c /. FindRoot[torootL[a, c, z], {c, 0.001, 0.0000001, 1000}]

intS[a_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(1/x^d) (1/((1 - (x/zh)^(d + 1)) (1 - cz[a, z]^2 x^(2 d))))^(1/2), {x, 10^-10, z}, MaxRecursion -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 6, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive"}]
functionS[a_, z_] = intS[a, z] + 1/(z^(d - 1));
Plot[functionS[0.1, z], {z, 1, zh}, PlotPoints -> 8, AxesLabel -> {"z_s", "S"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large] // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming
```

produces the plot,

[image: pic2]

where the `Method` I used in the present is only `GlobalAdaptive` since if I use the `Method` in the old code it produces a flat line which I don't know why. Anyways, the old and present codes should produce the same plot especially in those region close to $z_s = 1.5$ to which in the first image you can see a minimum occurring around $z_s \approx 1.4$.

---

Why is this so? I'm still trying to understand the `NIntegrate Integration Strategies` documentation although it is hard to understand for me since I'm not a heavy user maybe until now.

I was thinking of maybe there is a different strategy to eliminate $c$ in the expression for $S$ using $\eqref{1}$ $\eqref{2}$ $\eqref{3}$ at the same time. Any comments?

---

UPDATE:

I noticed that when I changed the lower limit of the integral in `intS` I can get the same curve but with different magnitude so I think that cannot be correct.

```
intS[a_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(1/x^d) (1/((1 - (x/zh)^(d + 1)) (1 - cz[a, z]^2 x^(2 d))))^(1/2), {x, 10^-2, z}, MaxRecursion -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 6, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive"}]
```

[image: pic1]

```
intS[a_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(1/x^d) (1/((1 - (x/zh)^(d + 1)) (1 - cz[a, z]^2 x^(2 d))))^(1/2), {x, 1, z}, MaxRecursion -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 6, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive"}]
```

[image: pic2]

You can see that when I changed the lower limit to `10^-2` the curve already appeared but the magnitude is wrong, and when I set it to `1` the curve is there and the magnitude is closer to the original. However, I think I cannot just tune the lower limit, it must be the case that $\epsilon \leq z_s \leq z_h$ since $\epsilon$ is a regulator. Note that since that is the case, $z_s$ should approach $\epsilon$ first then take the limit where $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. So in the case of Mathematica I can just set $\epsilon$ to the machine-wise zero, I think $10^{-10}$ is considered to be 0 but not really setting 0.

Comment: It is true that $\frac{d a}{d z_s} = 0$ ?

Comment: @Cesareo Good question, I'm thinking that $a$ should depend on $z_s$ as seen from $\eqref{1}$, although in the end I can just give it a value. I think I should change it to $a=a(z_s)$.

Comment: It looks like this problem has no unique solution. May be we need to add some restrictions?

Comment: @AlexTrounev The only restrictions in the problem are that $S$ must be a minimum for some $z_s$ and $c$ is constrained by this fact.

Comment: @mathemania Are $a, c, z_s$ real? If $a, c, z_s$ are real then we have some restrictions for $c, z_s$ due to  convergence of  integral.

Comment: @AlexTrounev All variables and constants here are real.

Answer (score 1):

If all parameters $a,z_s,z_h,c$ are real, then we have constraints dictated by existence of integral $a(z_s,z_h,c)$. As an example let put $d=3, z_h=3/2, a=1/10$, from this data we can compute $c(z_s)$ as follows (we made substitution $y=x^{d+1})$:

```
d = 3; zh = 3/2;
a[zs_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
 c zs^(d + 1)/(d + 1) NIntegrate[
   Sqrt[1/(1 - (zs/zh)^(d + 1) y)/(1 - 
       c^2 zs^(2 d) y^(2 d/(d + 1)))], {y, 0, 1}]
```

Since `a[]` is real, we can plot this function with using  constrains for existence of integral

```
ContourPlot[(a[zs, c] - 1/10) Boole[c^2 zs^(2 d) <= 1] == 0, {zs, 0, 
  zh}, {c, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Figure 1]
The line on this picture is function $c(z_s)$ we got from the  existence of integral. Now we can calculate this function directly. Let check that

```
 cc[zs_] := 
 c /. FindRoot[(a[zs, c] - 1/10) Boole[c^2 zs^(2 d) <= 1] == 0, {c, 0,
     1}, Method -> "Brent"]

 cc[.781598]

Out[]= 0.99999
```

This is starting point we use in a loop

```
zs = .79; 
cr[0] = cc[zs]; Do[zs = zs + .01; 
 cr[i] = c /. 
   FindRoot[(a[zs, c] - 1/10) Boole[c^2 zs^(2 d) <= 1] == 0, {c, 
     cr[i - 1]}];, {i, 1, (zh - 79/100) 100}]

lst1 = Table[{(79 + i) .01, cr[i]}, {i, 0, 150 - 79}];
```

Plot this list and compare with Figure1 above

```
ListPlot[Join[{{.781598, 1}}, lst1], 
 AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(s\)]\)", "c"}]
```

[image: Figure 2]
Now we can interpolate data and use it to compute integral $S(z_s)$

```
fc = Interpolation[Join[{{.781598, 1}}, lst1]];

S[zs_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  x^-d/Sqrt[(1 - (x/zh)^(d + 1)) (1 - fc[zs]^2 x^(2 d))], {x, .782, 
   zs}]
```

Finally we plot $S(z_s)$ and check that there is no local minimum with $S'(z_s)=0$. Also pay attention that due to $c(z_s)$ definition we define $\epsilon $ as $\epsilon =0.782$

```
Plot[S[zs], {zs, 0.782, zh}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(s\)]\)", "S"}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Now we can extend this research for general case when `a` follows a list, for example

```
d = 3; zh = 3/2; a0 = {1/20, 1/10, 1/5}; 
a[zs_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
 c zs^(d + 1)/(d + 1) NIntegrate[
   Sqrt[1/(1 - (zs/zh)^(d + 1) y)/(1 - 
       c^2 zs^(2 d) y^(2 d/(d + 1)))], {y, 0, 1}];
Table[plot[i] = 
  ContourPlot[(a[zs, c] - a0[[i]]) Boole[c^2 zs^(2 d) <= 1] == 0, {zs,
     0, zh}, {c, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(s\)]\)", "c"}, 
   PlotLabel -> a0[[i]]], {i, 3}]
```

[image: Figure 4]

We can extract data directly from `plot[i]` as follows

```
point = Table[
   plot[i] // 
    Cases[#, GraphicsComplex[points_, ___] :> points, Infinity] &, {i,
     Length[a0]}];
```

Using `point` we can define `c=f[i][rs]` and `S[rs,i]`, and plot it as

```
Table[f[i] = Interpolation[point[[i]] // First], {i, Length[a0]}];

x0[i_] := Last[point[[i]] // First] // First

S[zs_?NumericQ, i_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  x^-d/Sqrt[(1 - (x/zh)^(d + 1)) (1 - f[i][zs]^2 x^(2 d))], {x, x0[i],
    zs}]

Table[Plot[S[zs, i], {zs, x0[i], zh}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(s\)]\)", "S"}, 
  PlotLabel -> a0[[i]]], {i, Length[a0]}]
```

[image: Figure 5]

Note, this solution is available due to constraints follow from the suggestion that `a, rh,rs,c` are real only.